# Issue with PHP insert to SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Im pretty new to PHP and SQL and I have been following some tutorials. I am trying to insert some simple items into an existing table (and yes the names are exact on the table, login info etc...)

Here is the error I am getting:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' ('username', 'email') VALUES ('Testname', '123')' at line 1

Here is my string:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'user' ('username', 'email') VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());
```

any ideas?

Comment: As you're new to PHP, you should be learning either PDO or MySQLi. MySQL is out dated now and has many security issues.

Comment: please try this code ,make sure that your database connectivity is eastablished.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'user' (username,email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a difference between ' and ` sign, when you need to call columns you need to cover them with

` sign not with single quote sign '

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `email`) VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: this worked, thanks!!, I didnt realize they were typing ` rather than ' in the tutorial.. on the screen it looked the same.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (username, email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: 'user' is still cover with single quote

Comment: Replace with `\`` or remove `'` completely from `user`.

Comment: still get an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' (username, email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')' at line 1

Comment: Replace with ` or remove ' @RobHopper

Comment: and also you can do without back quote: like write user instead of ''user' @RobHopper

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This gives me :Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: if you want to restrict column names with values you can use it as below.
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username,email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (username,email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
Use table name correctly (user).

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO user('username', 'email') VALUES('Testname', '123')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in mysql queries between the quote (') and the back-quote (`). The back quote is used to quote names of tables, databases and columns. The normal quote is used to undicate that the given value is a string and not a reference.

so your query should look like

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `email`) VALUES ('Testname', '123)")
```

because "user" is a preserved word as "username" so I put those around back-quotes so mysql knows it's an reference and not a function or property.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP MYSQL Single quote is not use for field name and table name unlike Oracle

You can use

```
INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES ('Testname', '123')
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`username`, `email`) VALUES ('Testname', '123')
```

instead of ' single quote Tiled can be used.....

if you dont want to use then its okey just use Tiled for reserve words in query like `status` or `order` etc

and as per @Andy said use mysqli driver for connection because mysql_query will bedeprecated in next version